# Connection String error in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-pooling

I use this Connection string for my project:

```
Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Database.mdf;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=Yes;user instance=true;
```

but when execute my program got an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: your databse name is "Database" this is worst database name I have seen :)

Comment: Is the file present in the D:\\ disk? Also check if there is no access issue to the file - check permissions.

Comment: is this `\\SQLExpress` is your instance name

Comment: I think the problem is on the access to the computer that stored the db file.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: My Database name is not database just change it for security reason. yes file exist

Comment: I use this instance for creating a installer who works in any computer.

Comment: Make sure that the machine where the SqlExpress is running is reachable from the client computer and also ensure that the SqlExpress service is running, or the name of the service is correct.
This error comes up even if the name of the database that you have specifeid is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your SQL Server Browser service is running by using SQL Server Configuration Manager and please check the network protocols as per below image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be the `MSSQLSERVER` service in `Component Service` under `Administrative Tools` is not working. Please check. if not then are you able to LoggedIn your `SQL Management Studio` (if Have)?